# Call to a member function extension() on string

Tags: php, string, laravel, member

I have tried to upload the image using Postman and the image is stored in the preferred directory and the full path is stored in database but i am getting the error response

"message": "Call to a member function extension() on string",

here is my code

```
public function store(AvatarUploadRequest $request, UserService $userService) {
$user = $request->user();
try {

$file = $request->file('avatar');
$file = url("/avatars") . "/" . $user->uuid . ".jpg";
$destinationPath = "avatars";
$user->avatar = $request->file('avatar')->move($destinationPath, $file)
->getClientOriginalExtension();
$user->avatar = $file;
$user->save();
  $userService->updateAvatar($user, $file);
} 
catch (\Exception $e) {
  return jsonApiResponse([
    'avatar' => $e->getMessage(),
  ], 422);
}
return jsonApiResponseWithData($user, 201);
```

}

Comment: In the snippet you have shown there are no occurrence of `extension` function. Please show error stracktrace with line numbers and show correct block of code.

Comment: ->getClientOriginalExtension(); is probably whats causing that problem

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same error. I realized I had missed this in `form`:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add 
`enctype="multipart/form-data"` - in the form:

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ...
</form>
```

so you can use function like extension() or validator like

> "mimes : png , jpg , jpeg"

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line (it seems you do not use it anyway):

```
->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

So this should work:

```
public function store(AvatarUploadRequest $request, UserService $userService) {
    $user = $request->user();
    try {
        $file = $request->file('avatar');
        $file = url("/avatars") . "/" . $user->uuid . ".jpg";
        $destinationPath = "avatars";
        $user->avatar = $request->file('avatar')->move($destinationPath, $file);
        $user->avatar = $file;
        $user->save();
        $userService->updateAvatar($user, $file);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         return jsonApiResponse([
             'avatar' => $e->getMessage(),
         ], 422);
    }
    return jsonApiResponseWithData($user, 201);
}
```